# What's the adverb version of "pleased"

Tags: adverbs

I want to say "she had a pleased smile on her face" but in the form of "she smiled pleased(-ly?)".

I just can't seem to find the right word.

It's driving me nuts.

Comment: “She smiled”:  why else would she smile but because she was pleased?

Comment: Maybe she smiled mischievously, or sadly, or  insecurely. But I want to emphasize how extremely content she is.

Comment: Well, if you set the right context it will be clear.  ‘Less is more’, as they say.  Or “she responded with or returned a smile”

Comment: Yes, that's how I have been doing it. "She responded with a pleased smile." But it bothers me that I can't use it as an adverb, like I do in my native language, Swedish. We have the adverb "nöjt", which would be the same as "pleased-ly".

Comment: There is _pleasingly_, but that would mean her smile pleased someone else.  How about checking a thesaurus for synonyms of ***happily*** and report back what you found and why you didn't like any of those options?

Comment: That was a really good idea! I found "gleefully", which I think is pretty close to what I'm looking for. Google describes "gleefully" as "- done in an exuberantly or triumphantly joyful manner". This is good. The word needs to contain triumph as well as content.

Comment: You might also want to [take the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), read up on [how to ask a good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and maybe even check out the list of [available tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/) (hint: you probably want the [single-word-requests tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) but note that it has some strict requirements.)

Comment: Perhaps *pleasantly*!

Answer (score 2):

The adverbial form of “pleased” is [“pleasedly.”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pleasedly) If you ever need to know the different forms of a word, check an accredited dictionary. Incidentally, not every word can be made an adverb by suffixing it with an -ly, but you may already know this.

Comment: While correct, it's not really in common use. A similar way of expressing this that nobody would find at all strange is to say, "*She smiled in a pleased fashion.*" It's longer but also more easily recognized. So, it's a matter of style which to use.

Comment: @JasonBassford It may not be in “common use” because people might not realize that it is indeed a valid adverb. And the fact that a word isn’t commonly used is not a reason to avoid using it.

Comment: @JasonBassford “Pleasedly” is, I would say, just as common as “minorly”; and “minorly” is a perfect valid and usable adverb.

Comment: While I would pronounce *pleased* as a single syllable word, *pleasedly* would be pronounced with three.

Comment: @jxh And? What does it matter if it’s three syllables?

Comment: @TheWordsmith I think it only makes a difference in how it sounds when spoken. One way sounds more like a word I recognize than the other way.

Comment: @jxh Regardless of how it sounds, it is an absolutely valid adverb.

Comment: @TheWordsmith I never suggested otherwise. Have an upvote.

Comment: @jxh No harm, no foul. :-)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pleasedly%2Cminorly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpleasedly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminorly%3B%2Cc0    and for some context:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pleasedly%2Cminorly%2Cgratefully%2Cplayfully&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpleasedly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminorly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgratefully%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplayfully%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Jim Au contraire! Thank you for pointing this out. “Pleasedly” is *more* common than “minorly”! How unexpected! And, if it pleases you, [see this.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-majorly-wrong-to-use-minorly)

Comment: The usage of a word by society doesn’t always validate or invalidate said word.

Answer (score -1):

**Contently** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Contently)

> adv.    1.  In a contented manner.

from [content](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/content) 2

> 1. Desiring no more than what one has; satisfied.

As in:

She smiled **contently**!

[**pleasedly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pleasedly) is a word too!

Comment: Thank you, that works as well!  Though I take it there is no actual version of "pleased-ly", then? The way I see it, the word "pleased" contains more satisfaction than the word "content".

Comment: pleasedly is a word too!

Comment: Is it really!? My writing tool tells me it's not a real word, but when I google it, it actually seems to exist. It made me question reality.

Comment: @Ewandra Google isn’t knowledgeable about everything; if you need to know if a word is real or not, check an accredited dictionary, namely Merriam-Webster or the OED (among few others).